# How do I skip error messages for missing logs and continue to next log on /etc/logrotate.conf

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to configure a log rotation scheme but I want it to skip error messages for missing logs and continue to the next log. So far my configuration looks like this:

```
$ nano auth
/var/log/auth.log {
        rotate weekly
        rotate 7
        notifempty
        delaycompress
```

How do I tell it to skip errors messages?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with missingok to skip errors.

Comment: A few words of explanation would help.